# Do I need to return true and false in functions or just one?

Tags: php, function, return

Do I need to offer a true and false return in functions in php or is just a true return enough?

If I have a little function like so:

```
<?php
$name =  $_POST['name'];

function nameCheck($name)
{
if (strlen($name)>1 && strlen($name)<40)
{
    return true;
}   
    else
    {
        return false; // do I need this?
    }
}
```

And then am checking if it is false down here:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if (!nameCheck($name))
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Fail name!")</script>';
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

`if (!nameCheck($name))` wouldn't I only need to return a true value in my original function, as if it doesn't return true here, it will return false?

Comment: If nameCheck() is modified so that it doesn't return false, then it will return a null if the condition isn't met.... null !== false

Comment: I would drop the else, because it is useless. I would however always return a boolean. Because it is useful when you can expect a typed return value.

Comment: Why not simply modify your function to: `function nameCheck($name)
{
return (strlen($name)>1 && strlen($name)<40);
}`

Comment: you could stream line this: return (strlen($name)>1 && strlen($name)<40);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually don't *need* to return both as php will interpret a `null` as `false` if cast to boolean in an `if`, the way you are doing here.

That said, you might as well be explicit about it and return both in this case. You can write the function a lot cleaner if you do so:

```
 function nameCheck($name)
 {
     return strlen($name) > 1 && strlen($name) < 40;
 }
```

The value of `strlen($name) > 1 && strlen($name) < 40` is a `boolean`, **ie:** the answer is either **true** or **false**. So, we simply need to simply return the output of this calculation...

Lets think through how the machine will process this code:

`if(2>1) return true;`

The first thing it does is calculate the brackets:

`if(true) return true;`

With this in mind, we can simply say:

`return 2>1;`

This same logic is used in the function above

Comment: Then it will return false.

Comment: Added a little explanation for you below the function now

Comment: You use only one condition in your function, so it can be reduced to a simple line of code ; in fact, when you do a `if( condition )`, you are doing a test on the **return** value of the condition ; it can be seen as `if( condition == true )`. In your function with `if` and `else`, you just add more conditions ; you can simply use the `return` value of the test, 'cause it is the only test you do. ;)

Answer (score 3):

PHP is not a `typed language`, so it won't force you to return a value (for example, you can only return `true` when the parameters meet the condition.

However, as said in comments, it is a bad idea because it will be null when you try to access the `return` value (or unwanted value)

Think as it was a `typed language` : your function would return a `boolean`, and you will be forced to return either `true` or `false` depending on the condition. So your first example is good, you should keep this syntax ; you can make it lighter by returning `false` by default, and use a condition only to return `true`

```
function nameCheck( $name ) {
    if( strlen( $name ) > 1 && strlen( $name ) < 40 ) { 
        return true;
    }   

    return false;
}
```

EDIT : [cronoklee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20122281/1051410) is also a great way of refactor your code

Comment: Yep, I was writing as you answered, but I chose to took the way lightly different 'cause I think the author is not very used to PHP programming ; you answer is well, but if I had saw it as a newbie I think I wouldn't understand very well how it works :)